# How can I update data for a key using NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, xcode, nsuserdefaults

Hi i want to update data for key but it still stays the same my code is:

```
NSUserDefaults *userNamePrefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [userNamePrefs removeObjectForKey:@"mykey"];

    [userNamePrefs setObject:@"myNewStringValue" forKey:@"mykey"];
```

but it does not works it does not remove object and ignore to add new value for key, please help what am i missing

thanks

Comment: how did you figure out that is still the same?

Comment: I restart the app and debug it and the value was the same

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try calling

```
[userNamePrefs synchronize];
```

after you made your updates

Comment: Thanks a lot now i must go but i will accept it as soon as i can thanks again

Comment: more on [userNamePrefs synchronize];
Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes.

Comment: To add to madmik3, if your application crashes without a call to synchronize those changes will be lost although they will save on a successful exit. With multitasking if someone leaves your app changes a global setting for your app, then returns to your app you need to call synchronize to make sure you get the latest changes to the settings.

Comment: i understand is like commit; in sql and if the app crash the rollback is called am i right?